# Return data from Powershell jobs without the Job-Information

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

i'm running a job which looks like this

```
$myjob =
{
  # regerate some $data
  return $data
}
```

I start and receive my job like this:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock $myjob -Name "job1"
Wait-Job -Name "job1"
$result = Receive-Job -Job "job1"
```

Now i want my `$result` to contain ONLY the `$data` which was returned. However, when inspecting `$result` besides of the $data i see much more information which I don't want to be included in my `$data` array. The messed-up data starts something like this:

(**Returned Data:**)

```
State         : Running
HasMoreData   : True
StatusMessage : 
Location      : localhost
Command       :  # regerate some $data
                 return $data
JobStateInfo  : Running
Finished      : System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
InstanceId    : f7c63b33-d270-4fa8-8042-111edf9d86a6
Id            : 270
Name          : job1
ChildJobs     : {Job271}
PSBeginTime   : 03.12.2012 14:06:26
PSEndTime     : 
PSJobTypeName : BackgroundJob
Output        : {}
Error         : {}
Progress      : {}
Verbose       : {}
Debug         : {}
Warning       : {}
```

this repeats over and over again like 20 times. After that my real `$data` is listed. However: iterateing over the `$result` array is not possible that way. What can i do?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are falling prey to a common misunderstanding about powershell: All uncaptured output in a script is returned to the caller, not just the arguments to "return." Example:

```
ps> $s = {
    1..3 # write 1,2,3 to output stream
    return 4 # write 4 to output stream, then exit scriptblock!
    5 # won't be output
    return 6 # won't be output either
}

ps> & $s
1
2
3
4
```

The return statement is used to exit a function early, and to optionally write one or more objects to the output stream (in addition to other outputs already emitted.)

If you don't want something to get output, then use one of the follow syntaxes:

```
$null = mycommand 
mycommand > $null
[void] (mycommand)
```

The reason you're seeing two extra "job" objects in your output is that both `start-job` and `wait-job` return the job object created and waited for, respectively. The reason for this is to allow pipelining:

```
$results = start-job { ... } | wait-job | receive-job
```

What's happening here? Well, `start-job` creates a job and passes it to `wait-job` which waits until the job is complete, then passes the job to `receive-job`, which returns the results and is finally assigned to `$results`.

Following?

Comment: Well, this was enlightening and solved the problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too. I kind of worked around it by not using the `return` keyword; instead of exiting with `return $data` try just using `$data` as the last statement in your remote job:

```
$myjob =
{
  # regerate some $data
  $data
}
```

I don't know why this seems to work though.

I'm invoking my remote jobs like this too:

```
$job = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servers -FilePath $myRemoteScript -ArgumentList $myArgs -AsJob -JobName $jobName | Get-Job | Wait-Job
$data = Receive-Job -Job $job
```

Comment: Nearly perfect! but instead the details i posted in the **Returned-Data** Code-Block i still get two `System.Management.Automation.PSRemotingJob` entries returned (the types of those objects) before the actual $data. Any ideas?

Comment: The return keyword is not the only way to return things from scripts. See my answer above.

Answer (score -1):

I also faced the same issue where I want to exclde comments.
So the easiest solution is to write your comments using:

`Write-Host("Your comments ") -Fore Red`